# file_get_contents() not working with YouTube

Tags: php, youtube, file-get-contents

I'm trying to read the video information from youtube like this:

```
$vid='WwVZBfMlNPA';
$vurl='http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id='.$vid;
$contents=file_get_contents($vurl);
var_dump($contents); 
parse_str($contents,$info); //decode the data
```

If I run this code on my server, the `var_dump()` shows an empty array, but if I paste `$vurl` in the browser, it returns a file that I have to save.

Anybody know why `var_dump()` shows nothing. This code used to work, suddenly it is not working anymore.

Comment: Tested with php 7.0.30 cli. Received the vid information. Do you have any errors in the web server log?

Comment: actually yes, the error is "failed to open stream", it took a while to show up in the  log, but the error is thre

Comment: another error is "failed to enable crypto", on the get_file_contents($vurl)  line

Comment: other error PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify

Comment: Looks like YT is changing the request to a https. You need to do some research on the SSL YT is using. Most likely needs to be updated.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using, are you executing on CLI or through browser?

Comment: mulquin - im using PHP version 5.6.30, executing it from browser. The exact same code worked before. I didnt run the code in a long time, then i went back to it without changing anything now it doesnt work giving this error. Does it have anything to do with any SSL certificate i have on my server?

Comment: Im executing the php using "h t t p://www.example.com/script.php?..... " inside the script its doing the file_get_contents('http.youtube....");

Comment: Json K, if i paste the same url using "http"  in the browser it works, but calling same url using file_get_contents from php script causes the error

Answer (score 0):

Look at `$http_response_header`. It will probably show that youtube gives you a 302 and redirects to their [https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue...](https://www.google.com/sorry/index) page that explains that you may be blocked because of the way you try to consume youtube.